# Where to store rarely used long string in Android, in database or in .txt file? (Performance-wise)

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-external-storage

I have 24kB string from server which is OSRM routing string. I'm using this string when maps activity is opened in app (parsing it and drawing route). So, actually 5-6 times a day. I believe it's better off to store it in .txt file rather than database. What are pros and cons of doing so?

> Note: app fetches this string once a day.

Comment: I suggest you do what you feel is the simplest and clearest. Without more information a text file seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is modern enough, i doesn't matter file or db. If we are talking about a very very ancient device, then you might consider cost of parsing 24KB text and other processes you are doing on this string, and decide either.